# Only display wc_add_notice IF customer_postcode is not empty

Tags: php, if-statement

I have gleaned code on stack overflow that allows me to display notices with minimum cart totals based on Zip code.  I include the code below.

My PROBLEM is that the message automatically defaults to Zone 1.
Which means that if a new visitor (who actually lives in Zone 2) comes to the site, places items in cart, visits cart -> the error message for Zone 1 is already showing up.  The new visitor has not input their postcode yet.  The cart shipping calculator is where the new visitor will enter their postcode (zip code).

I don't know what will be a workaround for this problem, but I was wondering if one can add an IF statement before the Cart Notice code, that basically checks:  if customer postcode is not set yet, then display message: "Please enter your postcode".

Then, if customer_postcode is set, then display the minimum cart value messages based on zones as in the existing code already.

I hope I am making sense - and hope someone can help me.

---

//MINIMUM CART AMOUNT FOR CHECKOUT

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'required_min_cart_subtotal_amount' );
function required_min_cart_subtotal_amount() {
$zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_by ( 'zone_name', "1" . 'zone_name', "2" . 'zone_name' , "3" );

```
// Only run it in  Cart or Checkout pages
if( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) {
    // Get cart shipping packages
    $shipping_packages =  WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();
    
    //Get the WC_Shipping_Zone instance object for the first package
    $shipping_zone = wc_get_shipping_zone( reset( $shipping_packages ) );
    $zone_id = $shipping_zone->get_id(); //Get the zone ID
    $zone_name = $shipping_zone->get_zone_name(); // Get the zone name
    
    // Total (before taxes and shipping charges)
    $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;
    
    // HERE set minimum cart total amount (for Zone 1,2,3 and for other zones)
    // $min_total = $zone_id == 200.0 : 99.99 ? "1";

$min_total = 180;
if ($zone_id == "2") $min_total = 100;
if ($zone_id == "3") $min_total = 220;
    
    // Add an error notice if cart total is less than the minimum required

if( $total <= $min_total ) {
    // Display an error message
wc_add_notice(  sprintf(
    __("A minimum order of - %s is required.  Please enter your Postal Code in the Shipping section below.  Minimum orders differ from area to area."),
    wc_price( $min_total)
), 'error' );

remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout','woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);

}   
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'disable_checkout_button', 1);
}

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the code to add an IF statement to the cart page?  The IF statement should solve for:  if user has not entered a zip code, print notice: please enter your zip code to complete the cart; else if user HAS entered zip code, then show minimum order message based on zip code.